# Mockito's .when call seems to increase call count.

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

Using the following code:

```
@Test
public void testSetGameType_deathmatch() {
    CommandSender sender = Mockito.mock(CommandSender.class);
    String[] args = {"deathmatch"};
    Pvpgames plugin = PowerMockito.mock(Pvpgames.class, Mockito.withSettings().verboseLogging());
    plugin.settings = new HashMap<>();
    Server server = PowerMockito.mock(Server.class);
    PluginManager pluginManager = PowerMockito.mock(PluginManager.class);
    PowerMockito.when(plugin.getServer()).thenReturn(server);
    PowerMockito.when(plugin.getServer().getPluginManager()).thenReturn(pluginManager);
    PowerMockito.when(plugin.getServer().broadcastMessage(org.mockito.Matchers.anyString())).thenReturn(1);
    PowerMockito.when(plugin.getGameType()).thenCallRealMethod();
    Mockito.when(plugin.setActiveListener(Mockito.any())).thenCallRealMethod();

    boolean result = GametypeHandler.setGameType(sender, args, plugin);

    Assert.assertTrue(result);
    Mockito.verify(plugin).setActiveListener(Mockito.any(DeathMatchListener.class));
    Mockito.verify(plugin.getServer().getPluginManager()).registerEvents(Mockito.any(DeathMatchListener.class), Mockito.same(plugin));
    Mockito.verify(sender).sendMessage(Mockito.anyString());
    Mockito.verify(plugin.getServer()).broadcastMessage("Gametype has been changed to: Deathmatch");
}
```

When I verify `Mockito.verify(plugin).setActiveListener(Mockito.any(DeathMatchListener.class));` .setActiveListener has apparently been called 3 times, however tracing it with my IDE tells me it has only been called once.
So I enabled verbose logging in mockito and I get this as output:

```
############ Logging method invocation #1 on mock/spy ########
pvpgames.getGameType();
   invoked: -> at dk.zlepper.pvpgames.commands.GametypeHandlerTest.testSetGameType_deathmatch(GametypeHandlerTest.java:57)
   has returned: "null"

############ Logging method invocation #2 on mock/spy ########
pvpgames.setActiveListener(null);
   invoked: -> at dk.zlepper.pvpgames.commands.GametypeHandlerTest.testSetGameType_deathmatch(GametypeHandlerTest.java:58)
   has returned: "null"

############ Logging method invocation #3 on mock/spy ########
   stubbed: -> at dk.zlepper.pvpgames.commands.GametypeHandlerTest.testSetGameType_deathmatch(GametypeHandlerTest.java:58)
pvpgames.setActiveListener(
    dk.zlepper.pvpgames.listeners.DeathMatchListener@3ddc6915
);
   invoked: -> at dk.zlepper.pvpgames.commands.GametypeHandler.setGameType(GametypeHandler.java:22)
   has returned: "dk.zlepper.pvpgames.listeners.DeathMatchListener@3ddc6915" (dk.zlepper.pvpgames.listeners.DeathMatchListener)

############ Logging method invocation #4 on mock/spy ########
   stubbed: -> at dk.zlepper.pvpgames.commands.GametypeHandlerTest.testSetGameType_deathmatch(GametypeHandlerTest.java:58)
pvpgames.setActiveListener(
    dk.zlepper.pvpgames.listeners.DeathMatchListener@3ddc6915
);
   invoked: -> at dk.zlepper.pvpgames.commands.GametypeHandler.setGameType(GametypeHandler.java:22)
   has returned: "dk.zlepper.pvpgames.listeners.DeathMatchListener@3ddc6915" (dk.zlepper.pvpgames.listeners.DeathMatchListener)

############ Logging method invocation #5 on mock/spy ########
   stubbed: -> at dk.zlepper.pvpgames.commands.GametypeHandlerTest.testSetGameType_deathmatch(GametypeHandlerTest.java:57)
pvpgames.getGameType();
   invoked: -> at dk.zlepper.pvpgames.commands.GametypeHandler.setGameType(GametypeHandler.java:37)
   has returned: "Deathmatch" (dk.zlepper.pvpgames.commands.GameType)

############ Logging method invocation #6 on mock/spy ########
   stubbed: -> at dk.zlepper.pvpgames.commands.GametypeHandlerTest.testSetGameType_deathmatch(GametypeHandlerTest.java:57)
pvpgames.getGameType();
   invoked: -> at dk.zlepper.pvpgames.commands.GametypeHandler.setGameType(GametypeHandler.java:37)
   has returned: "Deathmatch" (dk.zlepper.pvpgames.commands.GameType)

############ Logging method invocation #7 on mock/spy ########
pvpgames.setActiveListener(null);
   invoked: -> at dk.zlepper.pvpgames.commands.GametypeHandlerTest.testSetGameType_deathmatch(GametypeHandlerTest.java:63)
   has thrown: class org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooManyActualInvocations with message 
pvpgames.setActiveListener(null);
Wanted 1 time:
-> at dk.zlepper.pvpgames.commands.GametypeHandlerTest.testSetGameType_deathmatch(GametypeHandlerTest.java:63)
But was 3 times. Undesired invocation:
-> at dk.zlepper.pvpgames.commands.GametypeHandler.setGameType(GametypeHandler.java:22)
```

So it seems like mockito counts it's own .when call as a call in the verify method. Have I done something wrong, or is this a bug in mockito?

Comment: These two lines:    `PowerMockito.when(plugin.getServer().getPluginManager()).thenReturn(pluginManager);`
    `PowerMockito.when(plugin.getServer().broadcastMessage(org.mockito.Matchers.anyString())).thenReturn(1);`

    Should be like this:

`PowerMockito.when(server.getPluginManager()).thenReturn(pluginManager);`
    `PowerMockito.when(server.broadcastMessage(org.mockito.Matchers.anyString())).thenReturn(1);`

Comment: @Mindaugas Thanks, but that doesn't fix the issue.